# Erro usando Lock Screen

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Estou tentando Bloquear a Tela com o seguinte código:

```
protected void onBloquear(View view) {

    DevicePolicyManager mDPM = null;
    mDPM.lockNow();
}
```

Fonte: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Porém dá o seguinte erro.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.lockNow()' 
on a null object reference
```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está ocorrendo porque o seu [`DevicePolicyManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) não está instanciado, então ele retorna nulo. Você deve conseguir receber um identificador para o `DevicePolicyManager` da seguinte maneira:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM =
    (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```

Veja [aqui na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html).